# I am getting this out error while running the program of JDBC with mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

> Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new
>   driver class is`com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is
>   automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver
>   class is generally unnecessary. Exception in thread "main"
>   java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue data manipulation statements with
>   executeQuery().   at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.checkForDml(StatementImpl.java:385)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:983)
>     at InsertJDBC.main(InsertJDBC.java:22)

Answer (score 1):

In your Class.forName() change it to 
Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver") from
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").Although current java loads the drivers without the use of Class.forName("") provided the jar is recognised in the classpath